# how can I get list of human name?

Tags: java, algorithm, dataset

In a document, I should detect the human name and extract it to the txt file. For this reason, I think I should have a list of human name in Eurape, US and Canada. Moreover, I will probably look at the name on the avaiable list and word found on the document. If they matched, I will extract them. However, the question is that "how can I get list of human name?". Or, do you know a open source project to detect name of human ?

NOTE: I am not asking recommendation on tools. IT is just a dataset, how can I reach it? A way.

Comment: In addition of being totally NOT intended for SO, this question is also very optimistic. Do you seriously think it could be possible to write a complete list of names (firstnames I presume) on such an extensive panel ? New names are invented everyday everywhere in the world...

Comment: @Bartdude so... how can I detect it? I am open to omit some new name, that is my goal is to achieve 90% success rate or more.

Comment: @TAsk in what way is it broad? tell me more

Comment: LET'S KEEP THIS OPEN - I FIND IT HIGHLY INTERESTING.

Comment: Is this from English texts?

Comment: @user3805283 > This question asks for a tool, shows no research, and probably violates other SO rules. Therefore it shouldn't be here at all in the first place. I don't have any idea how you could do it, and I would consider crazy anyone willing to build such a list that you ask, especially as it would be quite useless (except in your specific situation...). Now a lot of people have been considered crazy in the past and sometimes they're the ones to make the world evolve, so maybe you should start creating such a list... laune seems ok to help :-)

Comment: @laune Yes, it is from English text.

Comment: Search for _baby names_.

Comment: @Bartdude The 90% success provides some leeway. I have an idea...

Comment: Have [a look at this](https://www.drupal.org/project/namedb)

Comment: Have you thought about cases where a word will exist in any database of names, but most of the time that it's used, it won't actually be the name?  I'm thinking of words like "Fox" and "Angel".

Comment: @DavidWallace Of course, "Angel Heart" will be misunderstood for a person's name unless you can use the context. (Checking for quotes reduces failures.) But "20th Century Fox" need not be judged to be a person's name.

Answer (score 2):

Lists of first names used in English speaking countries are available. See e.g. http://www.world-english.org/boys_names_list.htm. (If you are looking for persons with German, French,... names it'll complicate matters, but there should be other lists around - I've seen one for German names.)

Put first names into a hash set.

Breaking a text into words is simple.

Iterate over the words and try to look up plausibles (e.g. first letter in upper case) in the hash set.

If you need to find full names, look at the following word(s) and check for possible middle initial ( "George A."), full middle name, and last name.

**This is full of holes, but I think that 90% could be achieved.**

Comment: OK.  Here are two pieces of text that you're bound to have difficulty dealing with.  "The Elector of Hanover moved to England and became King George I.  Bridges were built in his honour."  "My favourite author is George I. Bridges from Hanover."